# Были ли у кого проблемы с установкой программ с DreamSpark?

Tags: dreamspark

Такая ситуация: 
подал заявку на DreamSpark, на днях должен придти ключ.

И тут я задался вопросом: а будет ли мой компьютер проверяться, родные ли у меня программы?

Comment: Вы используете ОС с закрытым исходным кодом, и задаёте себе такие вопросы?

Comment: измените заголовок вопроса так, что бы он отражал кратко суть вопроса. То же самое сделайте и с метками.    
Иначе будете ждать совета/помощи очень долго...

Comment: очень уж похоже, что @futuramax - это реинкарнация пользователя @z-ziba из [этого вопроса][1] - оба называют DreamSpark DreamsPark'ом.  Ни у кого прежде не замечал такой ошибки



[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/260150/%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE

Answer (score 1):

У меня ничего не проверял, установил и все.